# Linking Anonymous User Session with Google Account results in broken redirect

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-oauth, mongodb-stitch

I am trying to link an anonymous mongodb stitch session to a Google account using the following code snippet from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/linking/):

```
function linkWithGoogleAccount() {
  user
    .linkUserWithRedirect(new GoogleRedirectCredential())
    .then(_=> alert("getting here"))
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

Further, I added `http://localhost:8080` (where I develop the app) to the list of *Allowed Request Origins*.

With the above code, I expect to handle the OAuth redirect similar to the [regular Google authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/google/) (which works fine).

However, when the alert `"getting here"` is triggered I see a GET 400 error with URI `https://eu-west-1.aws.stitch.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/myapp-abcde/auth/providers/oauth2-google/login?redirect=http://localhost:8080/&state=M2I...In0%3D&link=true&providerRedirectHeader=true`. After accepting the alert I get redirected to `localhost:8080/null`.

I assume I misunderstand some aspects of the whole procedure (it's hard to debug) and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you specify a redirectURI in users config in mongodb dashboard?

Comment: Hi @ParthChokshi. Thanks for asking. Yes, I read about that and use `GoogleRedirectCredential(window.location.href)`. I am now get redirected and end up on `https://eu-west-1.aws.stitch.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/auth/callback?state=...` with an error `{"error":"must start a new auth request"}`.